# Passing multiple form data to PHP controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

```
$('#save').on("click", function() {
      //collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
      var data = [];
      $('[name=form]').find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') != '') {
          var name = $(this).attr('name');
          var value = $(this).attr('value');
          data[name] = value;
        }
      })
      for (var i = 1, ii = form.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var name = 'form' + i;
        $('[name=' + name + ']').find('input, textarea').each(function() {
          data[i] = [];
          if ($(this).attr('value') != '') {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            data[i][name] = value;
          }
        })
      }
      $.post('foo', data,
          function(data) {
            console.log(data);
```

I have the above jquery code where I wish to post multiple form data into my PHP backend controller.

In my controller, I used

```
 $input = Input::all()
```

**Question 1**

How do I access the data in the array that I have passed?
Let's say I have foo input and bar input in my form. I tried to use

```
$input['foo']
$input['bar']
```

but I'm getting internal server error with undefined index error.

**Question 2**

How do I access the data of the data[i][name]? Let's say I have form1, form2, form3, so it my data array will become

```
$data[1][foo]
$data[2][foo]
$data[3][foo]
```

How can I access these in my PHP controller?

Thanks and sorry for the long question

Comment: I think we are missing some code for your `$.post` method that might be important. Also, that part appears to be incorrect as there is a single quote without a match.

Comment: @KJPrice my bad on the typo..fixed it

Comment: @KJPrice mind pointing out what is missing in my `$.post`?

Comment: Ah, I guess it makes sense. This assumes you are sending this to file "foo", but besides that, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

with FormData object.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("name", value);
```

on server-side you read values like this:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Comment: what about question 2? can I use this with it too?

Comment: Here you create array that contains key=>value pairs. So you can access any data that is inside FormData object. You can send type="file" input values too :).
If forms have input elements with same name you can do something like this.
for first form: formdata.append("name"+1, value); for second form ("name"+2, value);

Comment: thanks, I will try your method and see if i can get it to work

Comment: okay, here is simple usage of formdata object with ajax/jquery:
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'name', value );

$.ajax({
  url: '',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});

Comment: for `formdata.append("name", value);`, can I use a variable for "name" instead of typing "name"? means i want to set the name dynamically. is that possible?

Comment: yes, <input name="firstname" id="something"/>
var element = document.getElementById("something");
formdata.append(element.name, element.value);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74658/discussion-between-ddeme-and-tommy-lee).